# Erro compilando no CodeBlocks - Libboost

Tags: c, codeblocks, mingw, cmake

estou compilando aqui no CodeBlocks, já faz uma semana que estou tentando compilar, mas sempre da algum erro, e agora que está no final da compilação está dando alguns erros e não estou conseguindo resolver isso. Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso ? Obrigado a todos!

[image: Erro:]

```
-------------- Build: all in otclient (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking if target is up-to-date: mingw32-make.exe -q -f Makefile all
Running command: C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f "C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/COMPILE 2.0/Makefile"  VERBOSE=1 all
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\OTC -B"C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\COMPILE 2.0" --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start "C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\COMPILE 2.0\CMakeFiles" "C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\COMPILE 2.0\CMakeFiles\progress.marks"
C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/COMPILE 2.0'
C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\otclient.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/otclient.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/COMPILE 2.0'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\OTC C:\OTC "C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\COMPILE 2.0" "C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\COMPILE 2.0" "C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\COMPILE 2.0\CMakeFiles\otclient.dir\DependInfo.cmake" --color=
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/COMPILE 2.0'
C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\otclient.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/otclient.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/COMPILE 2.0'
[  1%] Linking CXX executable otclient.exe
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\otclient.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\otclient.dir/objects.a
C:\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\otclient.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\otclient.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe  -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-result   -pipe -mthreads -O1 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -mwindows -Wl,-Map=otclient.map  -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\otclient.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o otclient.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libotclient.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\otclient.dir\linklibs.rsp
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../lib\libOpenAL32.a when searching for -lOpenAL32
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../..\libOpenAL32.a when searching for -lOpenAL32
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lOpenAL32
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../lib\libvorbisfile.a when searching for -lvorbisfile
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../..\libvorbisfile.a when searching for -lvorbisfile
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvorbisfile
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../lib\libvorbis.a when searching for -lvorbis
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../..\libvorbis.a when searching for -lvorbis
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvorbis
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../lib\libogg.a when searching for -logg
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../..\libogg.a when searching for -logg
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -logg
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.idata+0x1a8): multiple definition of `__imp___ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.idata+0x1a8): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.idata+0x1c0): multiple definition of `__imp___ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.idata+0x1c0): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.idata+0x1c4): multiple definition of `__imp___ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.idata+0x1c4): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_DllMainCRTStartup@12'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.text+0x136): multiple definition of `_atexit'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.text+0x136): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.text+0x169): multiple definition of `__onexit'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:dllcrt1.c:(.text+0x169): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x190): multiple definition of `___gcc_register_frame'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x190): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x230): multiple definition of `___gcc_deregister_frame'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x230): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x7a70): multiple definition of `__ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD1Ev'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x1700): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x97d0): multiple definition of `__ZNK5boost6system14error_category23default_error_conditionEi'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x1770): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x9790): multiple definition of `__ZNK5boost6system14error_category10equivalentEiRKNS0_15error_conditionE'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x1730): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x9770): multiple definition of `__ZNK5boost6system14error_category10equivalentERKNS0_10error_codeEi'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x1710): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x7a50): multiple definition of `__ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD0Ev'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x16e0): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x4770): multiple definition of `_DllMain@12'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x13e0): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x4b88): multiple definition of `___dyn_tls_init@12'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xed0): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x4bfd): multiple definition of `___tlregdtor'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xf45): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x4fb3): multiple definition of `__pei386_runtime_relocator'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x12fb): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x4ff0): multiple definition of `___do_global_dtors'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x1338): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x501b): multiple definition of `___do_global_ctors'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x1363): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x5075): multiple definition of `___main'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x13bd): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x5098): multiple definition of `____w64_mingwthr_add_key_dtor'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x13ec): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x511c): multiple definition of `____w64_mingwthr_remove_key_dtor'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x1470): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x522e): multiple definition of `___mingw_TLScallback'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x1582): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x5450): multiple definition of `_VirtualProtect@16'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x169c): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x4af8): multiple definition of `__ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xe70): first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_thread_win32-mt.dll:tss_dll.cpp:(.text+0x5390): multiple definition of `_free'
C:/mingw64/bin/libboost_system-mt.dll:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x162c): first defined here
Process terminated with status 2 (1 minute(s), 9 second(s))
50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (1 minute(s), 9 second(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Os erros `skipping incompatible` é por causa do `mingw` que você está usando, você deve mudar para o `mingw64 POSIX`, sobre os erros da livraria `boost` você deve usar os arquivos `.bat` e executar para criar o CAMINHO em variáveis de ambiente do sistema.

Depois de executar verifique nas variáveis se o caminho foi realmente criado.

**Lembrando**: São dois arquivos `.bat` que vem junto com as bibliotecas `win32` disponibilizada na **github** onde você baixa o `otclient`.